# Eager loading of polymorphic collection class hierarchy

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy

My declarative class declaration looks like this:

```
class ExportJob(db.Model):
    # has foreign key to paramset
    backgroundtask = db.relationship(BackgroundTask, backref="exportjob")
    params = db.relationship("ParamSet")

class ParamSet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "paramset"
    paramvalues = db.relationship("Param", backref="paramset")    

class Param(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "param"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    paramset_id = fkey("paramset", index=True)

    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(50), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.Unicode(10))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }

class IntegerParam(Param):
    __tablename__ = "integerparam"
    value = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)    
    __mapper_args__={
        "polymorphic_identity": "int"
    }

class BoolParam(Param):
    ...

class DateParam(Param):
    ...

class SomeRelatedParam(Param):
    __tablename__ = "somerelatedparam"
    related_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(...))
    value = db.relationship(SomeRelatedModelClass)
    __mapper_args__ = {...}
```

My goal is to eagerly load (either using joinedload or subqueryload) an ExportJob with the associated ParamSet and all parameters of all types.

How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
q = ExportJob.query
q = q.options(subqueryload_all(
    ExportJob.params,
    ParamSet.paramvalues,
))
```

But how do I specify to eagerly load **all** the different Param types?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
q = ExportJob.query
q = q.options(joinedload_all(
    ExportJob.params,
    ParamSet.paramsvalues.of_type(with_polymorphic(Param, "*", aliased=True)),
))
```